# Real Time decreasing value in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need some advice and logic in my problem.
So, I have an entrydate, from database, then the running current date, and a value of 10(double type in database). So, I know how to calculate the diff of the entrydate and current date, right. So I convert it to seconds then to a number(9.23165).

```
|Entry      |Current Date|Diff(in number)|
|2:00:00 PM |2:30:00 PM  |   5.00(Sample)|(First User)
```

So basically, as current date goes on, can PHP show the deduction on real time? Or I need to refresh? What I need is for it to display the deduction without refreshing. So basically, I need to know what I have to do. Maybe javascipt and ajax?

Comment: Sounds like you just want to show a counter (basically) to the client. This should be done completely in JS, not PHP/Ajax needed.

Comment: PHP serves a request and close. It is not a language to perform persistent connections. AJAX could periodically do a request. If you want a persistent connection, I recommend writing a server in node.js. As Matthew said, trivial things like time difference can be calculated by JS as well.

Comment: im cool with using javascript or jquery, but im not familiar yet with node.js O.O

Comment: @MatthewHerbst  my time computation is made in php, if i pass that value from php to js, display it with docuement.getelementbyid is an html. will it show on real time?

Comment: thank you for your replies by the way!!!

Comment: What do you intend to achieve? JS has date/time functions. You could send a time difference as start value from PHP and then calculate further elapsing time in JS. Maybe do a periodical synchronisation after some minutes.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone oh i think i got the idea now, i got your point, then in your idea of periodical synchronization, that's like updating in every minute?

Comment: The client's clock in JS usually has a small inaccuracy after owers. Every 15 minutes or longer should be more than enough as long as the time base on server doesn't change, e.g. minutes since some last event.

Comment: Yeah, you really just need to port your PHP solution to JS. Even trying to sync with PHP every so often, will probably not be needed since the amount of time the AJAX request could take would also throw off your time.

Answer (score 0):

What you would need are a few Javascript/jQuery functions to update the browser in real time.

```
var myTimer;
var startTime;

function startTimer() {
  stopTimer(); // Reset
  startTime = new Date(); // Save to calculate difference
  myTimer = setInterval(clockTicking, 1000);
}

function stopTimer() {
  clearInterval(myTimer);
}

function clockTicking() {
  var now = new Date();
  var timeDiff = new Date(now - startTime); // constructor uses UTC, so use UTC date functions from here on
  var hours = (timeDiff.getUTCHours() < 10) ? '0' + timeDiff.getUTCHours() : timeDiff.getUTCHours();
  var mins = (timeDiff.getUTCMinutes() < 10) ? '0' + timeDiff.getUTCMinutes() : timeDiff.getUTCMinutes();
  var secs = (timeDiff.getUTCSeconds() < 10) ? '0' + timeDiff.getUTCSeconds() : timeDiff.getUTCSeconds();
  $("<element-where-you-display>").html(hours + ':' + mins + ':' + secs);
}
```

In Javascript you can call startTimer() to kick it off.

Comment: i think this is just to complicated with what I am using.. I will try it though, thanks!